# Extracting values of some columns with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, python-2.7, arcgis-10.5

I've been trying to run some code to extract the values from a column and random sample some of them.
The problem is when I try to append values from the cursor to a list. 
When I append values to the list, it works, but it appends the value inside a tuple and with a comma.
Here is some sample of the code:

```
import arcpy
import random

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
ws = r'D:\Projeto_VANT\SIG\proc_parc.gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace = ws

teste = r'teste'
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(teste, "ID_TALHAO") as cursor:
    list = []
    for x in cursor:
        list.append(x)
    print(list)
    sample = random.sample(list, 2)
    print(sample)
```

And this is the results (list of values and the sample) I got which were printed:

```
[(5,), (13,), (20,), (30,), (38,)]
[(30,), (13,)]
```

How can I extract these values and append them to a list as integer, outside the tuple and without comma?

Comment: When you loop over a cursor it always yields a tuple of the same length as the number of fields you've asked for.  Either unpack your single value immediately `for x, in cursor:` or specify the index within the tuple `list.append(x[0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` as a variable name might get you into trouble caio, try to make it a habit to prefix (*my*Var, *p*Var etc) or proper case (ProperCaseExample) your variable names otherwise you might end up overwriting a keyword. **Python is lax in its protection of keywords and will not even issue a warning if you do overwrite one**. Most python keywords are all lower case, `True` and `False` being notable exceptions, therefore declaring your variable names in any case other than lower case reduces the risk of problems later. Consider this:

```
list         # list is a keyword, python already knows what it is
<type 'list'>
list()       # returns a new, empty list but could also convert a tuple into a list
[]
list = [1,2] # oops, we've just overwritten list with a value
list         # now list is no longer <type 'list'> it's now [1,2]
[1, 2]
list()       # as list has been overwritten you can no longer use it as before
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Because you've overwritten the builtin object `list` if you later decide to use `list(myTuple)` to convert a tuple into a list, a handy approach as tuples are read only and if you want to change or remove values do so as a list object then convert back to a tuple. Now that `list` is overwritten python is going to throw an exception and you will struggle for a very long time trying to find the error in syntax that checks out 100% with every reference and the problem could be hundreds of lines before.

Another option to append elements into a list that works for me is `list += x` which works if x is a tuple or list. The [addition assignment operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/assignment_operators_example.htm) (`+=`) also works for lists of more than one element:

```
myList = [1,2] 
myList += [3,4] 
myList is now [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Append has a different behavior with lists:

```
myList = [1,2] 
myList.append([3,4])
myList is now [1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

Which is probably not what was intended but is great if you know this quirk and are prepared for list or tuple items in your list.

In your code:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(teste, "ID_TALHAO") as cursor:
    list = []
    for x in cursor:
        list += x
    print(list)
    sample = random.sample(list, 2)
    print(sample)
```

or as a [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```
list = [x[0] for x in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(teste, "ID_TALHAO")]
```

Note that the addition assignment is not valid here, you need to use indexing as Hornbydd indicates in his answer.

Comment: I appreciate your tips! Since I have just started with programming every tip is helpful! About what you said of naming the a variable with the word "list", I was only providing a sample of my problem, it is not what is written in the code, but thanks for the helpful tips anyway, I didn't know very well how things occur "behind the scenes", in the environment. Also, thanks for explained the two ways of doing what I want! Congratulations for your work.

Answer (score 6):

Replace `list.append(x)` with `list.append(x[0])`

x is a tuple of 1 and when you add those to lists or convert to strings you get that (x,) notation.