# Using os.walk and addDataFromPath to add multiple shapefiles from directory to map

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-pro

I am attempting to add all the shapefiles from a single directory into an ArcGIS Pro map. Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import os 

path = # directory path
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
map = aprx.listMaps()[0]


for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for file in filenames:
                if file.endswith("shp"):
                    map.addDataFromPath(os.path.join(dirpath,file))
```

But this only manages to add the very first shapefile that it finds, and then provides this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File #script location, line 12, in <module>
    map.addDataFromPath(os.path.join(dirpath,file))
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\_mp.py", line 1771, in addDataFromPath
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.addDataFromPath(*gp_fixargs((data_path,), True)))
RuntimeError
 Failed to execute (AddShapefiles).
```

However, when I replace `map.addDataFromPath(os.path.join(dirpath,file))` with `arcpy.AddMessage(os.path.join(dirpath,file))`, the geoprocessing message does actually list out every shapefile within the directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not a PRO user but in Desktop you need to create a layer from the feature class then add the layer to the map. If addDataFromPath expects a .lyr file and you give it a .shp file it might not have the capacity of creating a layer on the fly. I notice your variables are all lower case, I *strongly* recommend not using all lower case variables, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365814/extracting-values-of-some-columns-with-arcpy/365835#365835 where all lower case variable names has got a user into difficulty.

Comment: Could you please report a result from `print(os.path.join(dirpath,file))`?

Comment: @Aaron When I use print when running the script from my toolbox it does nothing, but when I run it from the python window in Pro it gives me a list of all shapefiles in the directory, the same as AddMessage does in the toolbox.

Comment: @MichaelStimson When I remove os.walk and just specify a single shapefile then addDataFromPath does add it to the map.  And even with os.walk it is adding the first shapefile it finds, but none of the subsequent ones. Good tip re: the lower case variables, that seems like good practice. I did change mine in this instance but am still getting the same result.

Comment: The post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265592/adding-feature-class-to-map-in-current-project-using-arcpy-in-arcgis-pro supports using a data path in the accepted answer, in that case a single layer is successfully created with the addDataFromPath method. Is it possible the shapefile is corrupt? Could you put your addDataFromPath into a try: except: block and see if it's just one shapefile that's gumming up the works.

Comment: @MichaelStimson A-ha! The try: except: worked a treat, and the second shapefile in that directory appears to be corrupted, along with several others. The rest all were added to the map successfully! Thanks for your help. What is the preferred way for me to resolve this thread now?

Comment: @MichaelStimson Nice troubleshooting! Would you be willing to write up an answer from your comments so we can consider this question resolved?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I can do that. I will update with an explanation and my updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turned out that the problem was some corrupted shapefiles. It was suggested that I put `addDataFromPath` in a try: except block, and that let the script ignore the corrupt files and continue running. Here is my updated working code (including renamed variables to ensure there were no keyword conflicts):

```
import arcpy
import os 

myPath = "Z:\Open_spaces_and_environment\Parks_Environment_Ecology"
myAprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
myMap = aprx.listMaps()[0]


for myDirpath, myDirnames, myFilenames in os.walk(myPath):
            for file in myFilenames:
                if file.endswith("shp"):
                    try:
                        myMap.addDataFromPath(os.path.join(myDirpath,file))
                    except Exception:
                        arcpy.AddMessage(os.path.join(myDirpath,file))
```

Comment: Excellent! When you get an exception you can also use arcpy.AddWarning https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addwarning.htm or arcpy.AddError https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/adderror.htm depending on how serious the problem will be when the try fails.. You can also get specific information with GetMessages https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/getmessages.htm to put into the error message. I would also advise using if os.path.splitext(file.lower())[1]=='.shp': instead of endswith("shp"), it's a bit more robust.